# Why is my if/then statement running through both sets of actions?

Tags: jquery, if-statement

For some reason this code is running the if statement and then the else statement as if there is no logic at all and I had just written the commands out one after the other. The really weird thing is that it's working perfectly fine in JS Fiddle so I can't even really re-create the problem.

```
    $('.acc-trigger').click(function () {
    if (!$(this).next().children('li.sideBarSubNav ul').is(":visible")) {
        $('.subnavReveal').text('►');
        $('li.sideBarSubNav ul').slideUp(300);
        $(this).children('span').text('▼');
        $(this).next().children('li.sideBarSubNav ul').slideDown(300);
    } else {
        $(this).children('span').text('►');
        $(this).next().children('li.sideBarSubNav ul').slideUp(300);
    }
});
```

JS FIddle of working code - http://jsfiddle.net/QNjR7/

Comment: If you can't re-create the problem with this code then it's likely that the problem isn't with this code.  Are you sure your browser isn't using a cached version of the JavaScript?  Maybe something else is wrong?

Comment: Put `()` around your if arguments: `if (!($(this.....visible))) {`

Comment: do you happen to have that javascript included twice on the page?  Add a console.log and see if the event is registered twice.

Comment: That was the problem bmorgan21, thanks. The back-end developer had added a link to the js file on the include and I had already put it in the master file.